# difference between 2 commands in Unix AIX

Tags: unix, diff, ksh, aix

I need to find difference between 2 Cmd outputs.  I found this Cmd for Linux but it is not working for Unix AIX server.

```
diff <(cmd1) <(cmd2)
```

Please let me know the equivalent UNIX command.

Answer (score 1):

The command you refer to is using `process substitution`, i.e. the `<(...)` part. Essentially, it takes the output of the `cmd1` and presents it *as though it were a named file in the filesystem* to `diff`. It is a feature of the `bash` shell, so, for a start you need to ensure you are using `bash` and not `sh`.

If that doesn't solve the problem, you could try downloading and installing the latest `bash` for AIX.

If that doesn't work, you need to use 2 temporary files, something like this (or using `mktemp`):

```
cmd1 > tmp1_$$
cmd2 > tmp2_$$
diff tmp1_$$ tmp2_$$
rm tmp?_$$
```

Comment: I believe the <(...) syntax also ses the /dev/fd/N device driver which AIX does not have.  bash has to pass some path to diff for it to open.  On Unix, if the fd is open on fd 5, then /dev/fd/5 will also open that same fd.